# xampp mysql not logging to database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to a database but xampp is returning an error on my windows VPS

I tried changing port but It did not work

```
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-07-28  4:34:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-07-28  4:34:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1791432; transaction id 163
2019-07-28  4:34:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-07-28  4:34:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-07-28  4:34:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-07-28  4:34:35 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2019-07-28  4:34:35 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-07-28  4:34:35 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I expected it to work but it didn't